# UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: portrait/landscape weirdness

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uinavigationbar, landscape-portrait

Switching to iOS5, I wanted to make use of a custom styled `UINavigationBar` using the following code snippet:

```
if ([navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:
                                                                         forBarMetrics:)]) {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBar.png"] 
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarLandscape.png"] 
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
    }
```

This works quite well, but: my custom image has rounded corners (c.f. the attached images) which causes the following:

Starting in portrait mode, it looks fine.

[image: Portrait (normal)]

Changing to landscape mode also looks good.

[image: Landscape (normal)]

Changing back to portrait mode however does not seem to change the image to *NavigationBar.png*, thus there is no rounded corner on the top right.

[image: Portrait (without rounded corner on the top right)]

Any advice on how to solve this problem is appreciated.

// edit

Adding the following code to my viewController removes this "bug"  but this cannot be the right solution!?!

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration { 
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation 
                                            duration:duration];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBar.png"] 
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarLandscape.png"] 
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As iOS6 introduces rounded corners by default, this problem will disappear soon.